# check for minimum amount in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that checks for a value between the range of 0 and 999999.

```
/^((?:\d{1,3},)?\d{1,3})(\.\d{2})$/
```

The problem is that 0.00 is valid.  I would like to set 0.01 as the smallest amount that is valid.  So, putting in 0.00 would me invalid.

I'm terrible with the black art of regex.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Use regex for checking format only. Then parse it to a number and do the maths in code, not in regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put logic into regular expressions.   They are for matching patterns, not doing numerical comparisons.

In Perl, this would be:

```
if ( $s =~ /^((?:\d{1,3},)?\d{1,3})(\.\d{2})$/ && ( $s > 0 ) ) {
    # acceptable number
}
```

Regexes aren't a black art if you use them properly.  Trying to do numeric calculations with them is not using them properly.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that regexes aren't the best solution for numeric problems

Comment: They're not the best solution for MANY problems.  Just because a problem involves a string doesn't mean you wave the magic wand of regexes at it.  It's a drum I've been beating for the past few weeks now.  I'm thinking of putting up a single-purpose website like http://bobby-tables.com/ or http://htmlparsing.com/ just to lay it all out so I don't have to keep answering the same think over and over.